# How to register an @api_view into router, and i can see it in API root page？

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This my test code,but it is not work：

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from apps.apis import views


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users1', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'hello', views.hello, base_name='hello')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^hello$', views.hello ),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

How to register an @api_view into router, and i can see it in API root page？Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Your view needs to inherit from `ViewSet` to appear in the routers.
This being said, you can simply turn an `APIView` into a `ViewSet` by adding the `ViewSetMixin`

Comment: Thanks your answer,but my view is a function view .How it inherit from `ViewSetMixin`

Comment: As I said, you can't.

Comment: You need to make it a ViewSet and override the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, but it might help someone else.
I create @api_view and i can see it in API root page without router:

Views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def testing(request):
   mydata = models.Test_filter.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.test_filter_serializer(mydata, many=True)
   context = {'mymembers': serializer_class.data}
   return Response(context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.testing, name='index'),
]
```